# Kubernetes. Is it possible to invoke a specific pod replica by TCP/IP?

Tags: kubernetes

I have a deployment configured with five replicas:

```
kubectl get pods

NAME                   READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
test-581957695-cbjtm   1/1       Running   3          1d
test-581957695-dnv8s   1/1       Running   1          1d
test-581957695-fv467   1/1       Running   1          1d
test-581957695-m74lc   1/1       Running   0          1d
test-581957695-s6cx0   1/1       Running   1          1d

kubectl describe services hellokube-service

...
Endpoints:      172.30.242.200:8080,172.30.242.201:8080,172.30.242.202:8080 + 2 more...
...
```

I need when a new replica is started that an external service contact with that replica to make some configuration on it.

Is it possible to connect directly with a specific replica using TCP/IP?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

May you can contact external service forwardly and request config info in new replica. In this way, problem can be solved easily.

Comment: I understand you mean that from the new pod, when it start, the new pod should contact the external service right? That would be great, but I'm working with a commercial product, I can not request the configuration actively. The workaround I see is to add a new deployment within a new container acting as a proxy. My pod register to that proxy to a specific port when it starts. Then through that proxy I can contact a particular pod using a specific port.